# react hook form set default values not working

Tags: react-native, react-hook-form

searched on internet and see `defaultValues` property does the tricks so prepared code below, but it still not working?

Whats wrong here?

```
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form';

export const ProfileForm = (props) => {
  const {register, handleSubmit, setValue, errors} = useForm({
    defaultValues: {name: 'test'},
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    register('name', {required: 'Name field is required'});

  }, [register]);




  console.log('errors', errors);
  return (
        <Input
          label="Name"
          placeholder="Enter name"
          onChangeText={(text) => setValue('name', text)}
          errorMessage={errors.name?.message}
        />)
}
```

Comment: please try to better explain the problem you are having

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a read at the `defaultValues` section in the doc for custom register, which is what you having in your code example above by `register` at `useEffect`.

> It doesn't auto populate with the manually registered input (eg:
> register({ name: 'test' })) because the custom register field does not
> provide the ref to React Hook Form.

To work around this issue.

1. `useController`: https://react-hook-form.com/api#useController
2. `register` input with its reference. `<input ref={register} />`