# defaultValues does't populate input field in react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form with Input "clientCode" and "clientName", props are being passed by Parent Component but it's not showing as defaultValues for my input field. Any idea what I do wrong? I've seen a lot of similar questions on SO and nothing works for me (using reset, using setValue).

I notice that my `console.log(props.client)` is being called twice, first time it's showing empty, but 2nd time it's showing correct value `{clientCode: "ABC", clientName: "Test Name", ...}`

```
const ClientAddEdit = (props) => {
  console.log(props.client); //result { clientCode: "ABC", clientName: "Test Name", ...}

  const { control, register, handleSubmit, reset, formState: { errors } } = useForm({
    defaultValues: props.client
  });

  return (
     <div>
        <Form className="mt-2" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <Label for="clientCode">Client Code</Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="clientCode"
                  className={errors.clientCode && "is-invalid"}
                  {...register("clientCode", { required: "Required", maxLength: { value: 10, message: "Max Length: 10" } })}
                />
                {errors.clientCode ? (
                  <div className="invalid-tooltip mt-25">{errors.clientCode.message}</div>
                ) : null}
                <Label for="clientName">Client Name</Label>
                <Input
                  type="text"
                  name="clientName"
                  className={errors.clientName && "is-invalid"}
                  {...register("clientName", { required: "Required", maxLength: { value: 100, message: "Max Length: 10" } })}
                />
                {errors.clientName ? (
                  <div className="invalid-tooltip mt-25">{errors.clientName.message}</div>
                ) : null}
       </Form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Is `props.client` asynchronously updated? In other words, is it possible that on the initial render that `props.client` isn't defined yet? Based on your description that sounds like what is happening. Can you include the parent code?

Comment: @DrewReese: no, but actually I've tried hardcoding the defaultValues by doing `defaultValues: { clientCode: "ABC", clientName: "Test Name" }` and it's still not working

Comment: This is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66248747/react-hook-form-set-default-values-not-working

Comment: @zecuria: register input with its reference `<input ref={register} />` will give me an error because `react-hook-form` v7 has different syntax, which I already use. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66927051/getting-uncaught-typeerror-path-split-is-not-a-function-in-react

Comment: It's not a duplicate. I copy/pasted your code into a codesandbox (changed `Label` and `Input` to standard HTML) and passed a `client` prop and it's working. Perhaps there's an issue with the `Input` component you're using? Can you update your question with a more complete/comprehensive code example?

Comment: @DrewReese: Oh yeah, you're right. standard HTML input is working, the `Input` I'm using is from `reactstrap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The issue you have is the react-strap `Input` component doesn't expose out a React ref to the input's DOM node, which the `register` function is trying to set.

## Solution

The `Input` props do however expose the underlying DOMNode via the `innerRef` prop.

```
Input.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  // type can be things like text, password, (typical input types) as well as select and textarea, providing children as you normally would to those.
  type: PropTypes.string,
  size: PropTypes.string,
  bsSize: PropTypes.string,
  state: deprecated(PropTypes.string, 'Please use the prop "valid"'),
  valid: PropTypes.bool, // applied the is-valid class when true, does nothing when false
  invalid: PropTypes.bool, // applied the is-invalid class when true, does nothing when false
  tag: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.string]),
  // ref will only get you a reference to the Input component, use innerRef to get a reference to the DOM input (for things like focus management).
  innerRef: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.string]),
  static: deprecated(PropTypes.bool, 'Please use the prop "plaintext"'),
  plaintext: PropTypes.bool,
  addon: PropTypes.bool,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  cssModule: PropTypes.object,
};
```

You just need to pass the generated `ref` to the `Input` component's `innerRef` prop.

```
const clientCodeProps = register("clientCode", {
  required: "Required",
  maxLength: { value: 10, message: "Max Length: 10" }
});

...

<Input
  type="text"
  name="clientCode"
  className={errors.clientCode && "is-invalid"}
  {...clientCodeProps} // <-- spread in as usual
  innerRef={clientCodeProps.ref} // <-- map the correct ref value
/>
```

[image: Edit defaultvalues-doest-populate-input-field-in-react-hook-form]